# How to configure static and media files with django and nginx?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have next settings.py on my local server.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_root")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_root")
```

I know that in production Nginx should handle static and media. Okay.
I use gunicorn and supervisor on my prod server.
My nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 194.87.95.46;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

    location /static {
        alias /home/split/static_root/;
    }


     location /media {
        alias /home/split/media_root/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8003;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
```

But nginx doesnt handle static and media, what's the problem?

Comment: You will have to expand a little on what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Comment: Show us a static file reference that is failing, both the django page template tag and the GET line from the web server log.

Comment: have you performed  python manage.py collectstatic  on server ?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* your issue is caused by trailing slashes - you haven't provided a trailing slash in the location definition, but you have in the alias. Try this instead:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/split/static_root/;
}

location /media/ {
    alias /home/split/media_root/;
}
```